# Foreach loops in Alpine.js from select dropdown

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I have a select option loop and wanted to try alpinejs. If a user selects a certain option, a certain DIV will show up.

Here's my select

```
<div class="mt-4"> 
<select required wire:model.defer="task_id" />
   <option value=""> Select a Task </option>
            @foreach($tasktypes as $task)
            <option value="{{$task->id}}"> {{$task->name}}</option>
            @endforeach                     
</select>
</div>
```

so if task->id == 1

a new `<div> id 1 should appear here </div>` should appear below.

I tried below to no luck. I'm just starting TALL Stack

```
<div class="mt-4" x-data="$wire.tasktypes->id : false"> 
<select required wire:model.defer="task_id" />
   <option value=""> Select a Task </option>
            @foreach($tasktypes as $task)
            <option @click="$wire.task->id = true" value="{{$task->id}}"> {{$task->name}}</option>
            @endforeach                     
</select>
    
     <div x-show="$wire.task->id"> some text here </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is from the mixing between livewire and alpine. The context is not clear from your question, but it can be achieved several ways:

Pure livewire:

```html
<div class="mt-4"> 
    <select required wire:model.defer="task_id" />
        <option value=""> Select a Task </option>
        @foreach($tasktypes as $task)
            <option value="{{$task->id}}"> {{$task->name}}</option>
        @endforeach                     
    </select>

    @if($task_id)
        <div> id {{ $task_id }} should appear here </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

or if you want it to be Alpine JS you could 'entangle' it with the livewire property:

```html
<div class="mt-4" x-data="{ taskId: @entangle('task_id') }"> 
    <select required wire:model.defer="task_id" />
        <option value=""> Select a Task </option>
        @foreach($tasktypes as $task)
            <option value="{{$task->id}}"> {{$task->name}}</option>
        @endforeach                     
    </select>


    <div x-show="taskId" x-html="` id ${taskId} should appear here `"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. 2nd one answered my question. Thanks